# INSERT into a table with condition not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data on it, student record. I am already using the table with some added data but the record is like half of the total. Now I have been given the complete record and I want to add it to my existing table. I want the `INSERT` to exclude the records that are already existing in my table to avoid duplication but the entire record of the new table get inserted into the my own table, creating duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO `studentTable`(`studentID`, `surname`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, 
`department`, `room_number`) 
   SELECT `studentID`, `surname`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `department`,
   `room_number` 
       FROM newTable WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM studentTable WHERE studentTable.studentID <> newTable.studentID);
```

**Note:** I can easily delete the old record and insert the new record but that will be to painful as the existing record is already in use with some added data.

*Any help will be appreciated. Deeply.*

Comment: Beside how to build the query, why don't you just make proper keys in order to not have duplicated entries

Comment: @RoyalBg: How do I achieve that?

Comment: You can achieve that when you alter the table and add unique index for the fields you don't want to be duplicated. Check for ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX syntax

Comment: Use joins http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php

Comment: Removed the sql-server tag because the syntax is obviously MySQL.

Comment: And the PHP tag as well

Comment: @RoyalBg: You mean after adding the index, I should run the same query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: How can that solve my problem? I am using MySQL.

Comment: after adding the unique index, you can run the same query. You might want to add something like `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id` in order to not stop the insert after reaching duplicate entry

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a primary key on `studentID` (if not, create one), just do `INSERT IGNORE` and mysql will do the filtering for you.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `studentTable`
    (`studentID`, `surname`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `department`, `room_number`)
SELECT
    `studentID`, `surname`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `department`, `room_number` 
FROM `newTable`;
```

Comment: Tried this but still giving duplicate records.

Comment: @Yax: What exactly do you mean by duplicate records? Because the surname/firstname, etc. can still be the same if the studentIDs differ, but with the PK there is no chance for duplicate studenIDs.